# Splice on forEach loop not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have the following context:

https://jsfiddle.net/eqntaqbt/2/

```
obj.forEach(function(user, index){
    var userName = user.name;
    console.log(index, userName);

  if(index === 5 || index === 2){
    obj.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

I am using a `forEach` loop and `splice` to remove the item in position `5` and `2` on the `obj` array. But for some reason its not working properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is working properly.. Don't see the logged userName, check the array logged at the last in your filddle.

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is splicing while looping. Spliced elements are accessed even they are no more existing. That leads to undefined elements.

You may consider [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj = [{ "index": 0, "name": "Odonnell Noble", "gender": "male", "company": "DIGIQUE", "eail": "odonnellnoble@digique.com" }, { "index": 1, "name": "Marie Oneal", "gender": "female", "company": "CANOPOLY", "email": "marieoneal@canopoly.com" }, { "index": 2, "name": "Adrienne Marsh", "gender": "female", "company": "XOGGLE", "email": "adriennemarsh@xoggle.com" }, { "index": 3, "name": "Goff Mullins", "gender": "male", "company": "ENDIPIN", "email": "goffmullins@endipin.com" }, { "index": 4, "name": "Lucile Finley", "gender": "female", "company": "AQUASSEUR", "email": "lucilefinley@aquasseur.com" }, { "index": 5, "name": "Pitts Mcpherson", "gender": "male", "company": "QUARX", "email": "pittsmcpherson@quarx.com" }];

obj = obj.filter(function (user, index) {
    return (user.index !== 5 && user.index !== 2);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Why his code is not working? Plz explain that. I think a reverse while loop might be the good choice to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> **The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first
>   invocation of callback**. Elements that are appended to the array after
>   the call to forEach() begins will not be visited by callback. If the
>   values of existing elements of the array are changed, the value passed
>   to callback will be the value at the time forEach() visits them;
>   **elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited**.

```
obj.forEach(function(user, index){
    var userName = user.name;
    //console.log(index, userName);

  if(user.index === 5 || user.index === 2){
    this.splice(index, 1);

  }
}.bind(obj));
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9qjmdeq/)

Answer (score 0):

forEach is rather meant for so-called side-effects.

The problem with your code is, that you are changing the array while you are iterating over it. So if you remove one item, all the other indices of the array are reassigned immediately. That's why after removing one item, further removals don't do the desired thing (at the desired position).

So forEach is good for effecting things that are outside the actual array, that is iterated.

This would be a perfect usecase for a function called filter, since that's actually, what you are doing with your list: you want to filter out some items.

```
array = array.filter(function(item, index) {
   return (index !== 5 && index !== 2)
}
```

Filter excepts a function as an argument, which itself will be called for each item in the array. If the function returns true for an item, it's kept - otherwise removed. That's why the logical expression must be slightly changed here: It reads like: Keep the items, which are not of index 5 and not of index 2. These sort of true-or-false returning functionas are called predicates.

What if you want to filter out some more indices? The expression using locical operators becomes quickly quite long.

You can instead use the array method indexOf on a list of indices, passing each time the current index of your array to it. Either this will return the a position or -1 if it's not in it. In the later case you want to keep the item in the array.

```
array = array.filter(function(item, current_index) {
   return ([2, 5].indexOf(current_index) === -1)
}
```

Also, you could wrap that in a function:

```
function removeIndices(array, indices) {
   return array.filter(function(item, current_index) {
      return (indices.indexOf(current_index) === -1)
   })
}
```

Finally:

```
array = removeIndices(array, [2, 5]);
```